# How to connect to SSL enabled Oracle database using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to Oracle database through SQL Developer. Our database is SSL enabled and runs with TCPS. In SQL Developer, I could not find any option where I can configure SSL parameters.

Does SQL developer support connecting to SSL enabled databases? If yes, how. I searched a lot about this, but could not find any relevant solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had gone through the mentioned document earlier. My question specifically asked for 'SQL Developer'. I am able to connect to Oracle from Java application and SQL*Plus with additional SSL details. Could you please point out if I missed anything in the doc w.r.t SQL Developer as I could not see any update related to SQL Developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find sqldeveloper.conf and add lines

```
    AddVMOption -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=point to your keystore.jks with Oracle certificate
    AddVMOption -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS
    AddVMOption -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=your keystore password
```

In the developer use custom JDBC URL like

```
    jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(protocol=tcps)(host=your dbhost)(port=2484))(connect_data=(service_name=your db_service)))
```

Comment: Thank You. The only difference for me was that i was used .p12 files instead of .jks , truststore type was PKCS12
What will be a good way to do this for various databases?. Changing sqldeveloper.conf everytime isn't practical